# Can you delete local static variable?

Tags: c++, static, singleton

I have my singleton class which returns pointer to local static of the instance for thread safety. Now if I didn't declare destructor as private can users delete it?

For ex.

```
class Singleton
{
    Singleton();
    public:
    static Singleton *getInstance();

};

Singleton *Singleton::getInstance()
{
    static Singleton inst;
    return &inst;
}

// in user code
void foo()
{
    Singleton *inst = Singleton::getInstance();
    // do its stuff

    //accidentally delete instance here?! 
    // Should I have private destructor?
    delete inst;
}
```

Comment: Not in this case, as nothing is allocated with `new`.

Comment: Do you often delete pointers accidentally? Because there is no universal way about protecting against that. Maybe return a reference instead of a pointer.

Comment: why would the user do that? everything can be broken and if you delete something that you dont own, you get what you deserve ;)

Comment: so deleting an object that is not allocated with 'new' is no-op?

Comment: I am not interested in how user should behave. 'You shouldn't do that' is not an answer

Comment: @BKC.: Designing an interface is all about being interested in how users should behave.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the case of trying to delete the pointer in `foo` if you make the destructor private it will cause a compilation error as the destructor is not accessible.  If `delete` was called in a member or friend of `Singleton` then it would still compile.  That said trying to `delete` a pointer that was not allocated with `new` is undefined behavior so we should try to make it where they user wont even accidentally try and call `delete`.

One way you can stop this though is to return a reference instead of a pointer.  That way you user never even tries to call `delete` since they are dealing with a non pointer type.

```
class Singleton
{
    Singleton() {};
    public:
    static Singleton& getInstance();
};

Singleton& Singleton::getInstance()
{
    static Singleton inst;
    return inst;
}
```

Comment: If the destructor were private, the call to `delete` wouldn't compile.

Comment: @juan It would if it were called from a member function of Singleton.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Yes, of course. But not from `void foo()` as in the example. Point is it can't be UB if it doesn't compile.

Comment: @juan Yes, but the OP can add another member function later and I think they are asking about  a cast-iron way of preventing an inappropriate delete. Could be wrong,  though.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I know what you meant, but be careful with saying " it can't be UB if it doesn't compile." :-)

Comment: @juanchopanza Added some more to the answer to show that at least in `foo` it would be a compiler error.

Comment: User can always get the address of a reference and delete it, if so their heart desires. +1 nevertheless.

Answer (score 3):

C++ guards against Murphy, not against Machiavelli, as the old saying goes. You can get a pointer from *everything* by taking its address, and then try to delete it. So even if your `getInstance` function returned a `Singleton&` rather than a `Singleton*`, nothing would stop the user of the class from doing the following and thereby invoking **undefined behaviour**:

```
auto& singleton = Singleton::getInstance();
delete &singleton; // undefined behaviour
```

If you make the destructor private, they can try to cast that restriction away with evil code like this:

```
delete (void*)(&singleton); // undefined behaviour
```

As a matter of fact, they may also try to call `free` on the pointer, which is even more evil:

```
free(&singleton); // undefined behaviour
```

You could argue that such accidents are more *likely* if the function returns a pointer. Then again, experienced C++ developers never attempt to `delete` or `free` something without double-checking if it's safe and necessary; I'd say if you have to deal with programmers who try to explicitly delete something returned from a Singleton's instance function, then you have a much bigger code-quality problem anyway.

That being said, nothing is gained from making `getInstance` return a pointer or by making the destructor non-private. By returning a reference instead of a pointer and making the destructor private, you sacrifice nothing but get a tiny safety bonus and some extra readability.

Answer (score 1):

> Now if I didn't declare destructor as private can users delete it?

Yes, a user can delete it.

It's your job to make sure that it's not easy for them to do so (a determined user with the intention to subvert your intention will find a way). Steps you can take in that direction:

1. Make the destructor `private`.
2. Change the return type of `getInstance()` to return a reference.

---

```
class Singleton
{
   public:

      static Singleton& getInstance()
      {
         static Singleton theInstance;
         return theInstance;
      }

   private:

      Singleton(){}
      ~Singleton(){}
};
```

Comment: The type of `theInstance` is missing on line 6.